# Is there a way to add base64 data: URLs to react-image-lightbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, react-image-lightbox

I would like to know is there a way to add base64 data URL (instead of image URL) to [react-image-lightbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-lightbox)

OR should I convert the base64 string to the image first and then add to react-image-lightbox? If so how can I convert to the image, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-lightbox-sandbox-rzfuh

Works for me.

When you want to use base64 you just have to replace the image url with the base64 string most of the time.

Comment: Work for me too. Thanks you vm for your help.